# pandas return SettingWithCopyWarning when trying to set values of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change a column value in pandas.
My current code is:

```
df.loc[:,"origin"] = df.loc[:,"origin"].map(my_fun)
```

The commands seems to work, but it returns a SettingWithCopyWarning.
I have also tried:

```
df.loc[:,"origin"] = df.loc[:,"origin"].map(my_fun).copy(deep=True)
```

but i got the same result. What is the issue?

My pandas is 1.1.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: No, because I am already using df.loc as the answer suggest

Comment: try `df = df.assign(origin = df["origin"].map(my_fun)`

Comment: Thanks, but with the df.assign command  I'm working in place. I iike the first option as I am not making additional copies.

Comment: I would just like to know why it is still returing the warning